# My date doesn't seem to be posting back in the form to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, razor, controller

My model has a object which has a date property...

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage="{0} is required")]
    [Display(Name="Donation date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DonationDate { get; set; }
```

The view has an editor for it....

```
  <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Donation.DonationDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("txtDate", Model.Donation.DonationDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "date"      })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Donation.DonationDate)
    </div>
```

The controller just receives back the model... but when I do this in the controller and give it to another view...

```
ViewBag.Date = model.Donation.DonationDate;
```

Every time I just get back 
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM  no matter what the date was set to. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Forgot to mention... I'm also using JQuery datepicker on the editor field:

```
    $('.date').attr("placeholder", "dd/mm/yy").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **TextBoxFor** so that the view engine knows how to label the form field appropriately (so that the model binder will recognize it on postback):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Donation.DonationDate, new { @class = "date" })
```

Alternatively, you could name the textbox correctly manually.  I'm not sure exactly what that would look like ...

**Update**

Ok, I as curious so I checked.  The naming convention for nested fields uses the dot notation.  So you should be able to write this:

```
@Html.TextBox("Donation.DonationDate", Model.Donation.DonationDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "date" })
```

**Update #2**

To format the correctly, apply an attribute to the **DonationDate** property in your model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
```

For this to work, you also have to use **@Html.EditorFor** instead of TextBoxFor.